# Sending data via bluetooth on Iphone (iOS 5.x)

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, mfi

I have been searching and searching, but found nothing yet. Is it really true that there isn't a straightforward way to establish a BT connection from my iPhone to another (3rd party) BT device, i.e. an audio receiver. I know this is possible through the OS (I own a Belkin BT music receiver that works this way - it appears in Settings and from there I can connect to it). Note that I am not interested in pairing to iOS-devices, but an iPhone and my custom made hardware.

I've managed to find Google's BTStack at code.google.com, iBlueNova, Celeste and more, which all must be run through Cydia or similar and also I stumbled upon Apple's MFI-program, which seems fairly complicated.

Does anyone have any experience with bluetooth and iOS, if so, how and where do I get started?

If one might be interested, the project I am developing involves a piece of hardware with a BT device attached on it. The app should be able to send simple commands via bluetooth (basically  just ASCII characters) to the device, which will react depending on what it receives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing accessories that need to connect to iOS devices and want to use your own communication mechanism then your only option is to join the Apple MFi program.

Comment: Thank. Sad to hear that. Do you have any experience with MFi - what does it cost, how long does it take to apply etc.?